# Не соблюдается weight в TableLayout из-за большой картинки на кнопке

Tags: android, android-layout

Имеется разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
android:background="#ff0000">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00f">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/month_label_text_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_right_large"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"/>
</TableRow>
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, не меняя фоновой картинки кнопки, чтобы все 3 ряда имели одинаковую высоту, занимая весь экран?

Comment: попробуй поменять  android:layout_height="0dp" на  android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii Попробовала - ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `TableLayout` с самого начала не подружился, но по опыту добавьте заглушку и раздайте дополнительные веса:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:background="#ff0000">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00f">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/month_label_text_view"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_next_month"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_right_large"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Dummy" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#000"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Результат (добавил первую попавшуюся большую картинку из google):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я прислушалась к совету Android Studio о том, что что-то из `TableRow` или `FrameLayout` лишнее. Убрала `TableRow`, обрамляющий `FrameLayout`, задав `FrameLayout`вес `1` и высоту `0dp`. И все получилось)))